# Complete this sequence of images

Tags: pattern, visual, sequence

This is a sequence of images. The fourth image is blank. Replace the question marks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it would be something like this.

> [image: Circles]
>
>
>  Rules:
>
>  Backgrounds depends on number of objects in it. Blue for 0, white for 1, black for 2.
>
>  If we number the segments left to right, top to bottom then shapes move like this.
>  Triangle - clockwise.
>  Square - stays in segment 2.
>  Pentagon - anticlockwise.
>  Hexagon - jump between segment 1 and 3.
>  If two shapes are in the same spot, the one with less corners will be the inner figure.
>
>  The colors move like this.
>  Red - clockwise
>  Yellow - stay in segment 2
>  Grey - anticlockwise
>  Blue - move between segment 1 and 3
>
>  If there are two shapes in the segment, blue is always the inner color
>  grey is inner if there are no blue
>  yellow is inner if there are no blue or grey
>  red is always the outer color.

Comment: You're correct :) Can you also edit/add a nice reason/explanation for it, for those who wants to see it.

Comment: Explanations added

Comment: Your explanations are correct, though the idea when having 2 objects in the same segment is that they "switch" color. F.ex if grey pentagon and red triangle would be in the segment, then it would be a outer red pentagon and a inner grey triangle .  Other than that, nice work.